# Physics in carrom like game using cocos2d + Box2D

Tags: physics, box2d, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on carrom like game using cocos2d + Box2D. I set world gravity(0,0), want gravity in z-axis. I set following values for coin and striker body:

Coin body (circle with radius - 15/PTM_RATIO):

```
density = 20.0f;
friction = 0.4f;
restitution = 0.6f;
```

Striker body (circle with radius - 15/PTM_RATIO):

```
density = 25.0f;
friction = 0.6f;
restitution = 0.3f;
```

Output is not smooth. When I apply `ApplyLinearImpulse(force,position)` the coin movement looks like floating in the air - takes too much time to stop.

What values for coin and striker make it look like real carrom?

Comment: For anyone that doesn't know the game: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrom

Comment: Study some [physics](http://www.khanacademy.org/#physics) and figure it out mathematically. (Worth having some general knowledge in that area anyway if you're a game developer)

Comment: @Jonathan Hobbs Not really fair as the issue here is related to the library and no amount of correct math would fix the problem out side of making his own engine,

Answer (score 3):

Box2D comes with a [FrictionJoint](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2FrictionJoint.h). From the docs:

> The friction joint is used for top-down friction. The joint provides
>   2D translational friction and angular friction.

As far as I know it doesn't really matter what you attach your physics-bodies to (using the joint). So you could attach them all to a border of the play-board and tweak the friction/torque settings until it looks realistic.

Comment: Removed my answer because the friction joint is the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setDamping`. It acts as air resistance.

```
object.setDamping(10.4);
```